# Marketing Cloud Triggered Send Failures - Seeing Error Code (140) that is undocumented in help docs

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, email

All new triggered email sends are failing within my Marketing Cloud instance.  This message error I am seeing is 140.

> GET https://SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/SENDKEY/deliveryRecords

Every send I attempt for every definition KEY has an error:

```
  "status": "Error",
    messageErrors": [
                        {
                            "messageErrorCode": 140
                        }
                    ]
```

This error code is not specified in help docs found here:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_email_send_error_codes.htm&type=5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the `requestID` at the end of the endpoint URL.  You have to include the Triggered Send Definition's external key and the `requestID` (or `recipientSendId`) returned in the response to a send.

**Send Response:**

```
{
    "requestId": "YOURREQUESTID",
    "responses": [
        {
            "recipientSendId": "YOURRECIPIENTSENDID",
            "hasErrors": false,
            "messages": [
                "Queued"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Retrieve:**

```
GET /messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:YOURTSDKEY/deliveryRecords/YOURREQUESTID HTTP/1.1
Host: YOURTENANT.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Authorization: Bearer YOURTOKEN
Content-Type: application/json
```

**Response:**

```
{
    "deliveryTime": "2021-06-16T11:33:37.793",
    "id": "e91917e5-6d5c-e911-a2e0-1402ec93898d",
    "messageId": "YOURREQUESTID",
    "status": "Sent",
    "to": {
        "address": "test@example.com",
        "id": 14,
        "key": "test@example.com"
    }
}
```

**Reference:**

[GET /messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:{key}/deliveryRecords](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/messageDefinitionSendsDeliveryRecords.htm)

Comment: The request Id is NOT required.  Omitting the request Id returns a collection of the requests along with the status of each.  

I did submit the Api request Id and recieved a more detailed error message, tho, so your response is helpful and I am marking it as correct.  

With request Id the error errors collection contains an actual message:

"status": "Error",
    "messageErrors": [
        {
            "messageErrorCode": 140,
            "messageErrorStatus": "The from email address is unverified"
        }
    ]

Comment: Not that I trust the official docs, but it does say that the `requestId`/`receipientSendId` is required.  I'd expect it to not work properly without it.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

RequestId is not required in the Api required.  Without requestId a collection of the the requests is returned.  However, adding requestId to the Api endpoint return a more detailed error.

Without requestId the error looks like (for each request in the results:

```
                messageErrors": [
                    {
                        "messageErrorCode": 140
                    }
                ]
```

With request Id, the error looks like (for the individual request queried):

```
"messageErrors": [
        {
            "messageErrorCode": 140,
            "messageErrorStatus": "The from email address is unverified"
        }
    ]
```